# Adding link to logo adds link to whole navbar

Tags: html, css

I added a link to the logo(image) on the navbar, but when I go to the page the whole navbar apart from the links becomes the link. How do I make it so that it only applies to the image?

As per comments I have uipdated the code with CSS and JS. I'm very new to web development, this may explain my lack of knowledge and overuse of CSS.

[image: Ref] the image.

```js
function navHamburger() {
 var x = document.getElementById("nav-links");
 if (x.style.display === "block") {
  x.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  x.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-row {
  /* margin: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-row #nav-links {
  display: none;
}
.nav-row a {
  color: #0075b2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-row a.icon {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-row a:hover {
  color: #19afff;
}

.main-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.mobile-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  color: #0075b2;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 4px;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #b36500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b36500;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

.desktop-menu {
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .nav-row {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .nav-row a {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 901px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1290px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="nav-row">
          <div>
            <a href="index.html">
              <img
                src="resources/img/logo/fullLogo.svg"
                alt="Archer Civils & Construction Logo"
                class="logo"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="mobile-menu">
            <div id="nav-links">
              <a href="pages/civils.html">Civils</a>
              <a href="pages/fencing.html" class="nav-mid">Fencing</a>
              <a href="pages/contact.html" class="nav-mid">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <a
              href="javascript:void(0);"
              class="icon hamburger-icon"
              onclick="navHamburger()"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="desktop-menu">
            <ul class="main-nav">
              <li><a href="pages/civils.html">Civils</a></li>
              <li><a href="pages/fencing.html" class="nav-mid">Fencing</a></li>
              <li><a href="pages/contact.html" class="nav-mid">Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: give the css and js file?

Comment: same as @KALITA and add them to a jsfiddle them share it here

Comment: You need to provide css n js file. Also I dont understant why you using <ul> list there, because in the image, you showing simple navigation bar. If you want to put them in line replace <div> tags with <span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `flex` for the main `nav` class, which takes full inline value:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/v5L3wdme/26/) to playaround.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-row {
  /* margin: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-row #nav-links {
  display: none;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.nav-row a {
  color: #0075b2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-row a.icon {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-row a:hover {
  color: #19afff;
}

.main-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mobile-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  color: #0075b2;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 4px;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #b36500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b36500;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

.desktop-menu {
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .nav-row {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .nav-row a {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 901px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1290px) {
  .desktop-menu {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav>
  <div class="nav-row">
    <div>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="Archer Civils & Construction Logo" class="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <div id="nav-links">
        <a href="pages/civils.html">Civils</a>
        <a href="pages/fencing.html" class="nav-mid">Fencing</a>
        <a href="pages/contact.html" class="nav-mid">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon hamburger-icon" onclick="navHamburger()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="desktop-menu">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="pages/civils.html">Civils</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/fencing.html" class="nav-mid">Fencing</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/contact.html" class="nav-mid">Contact </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

"display:flex" is the culprit here. Due to "display:flex" css property on the link, link is taking complete line. But it is not like that other navigation items has also turned into link but because link is taking the complete width and layered above the other navigation items it must be giving feel like other navigation items has also become a same link. You can refer the below screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .logo-link {
            display: flex;
            cursor: pointer
        }

        .logo-link img {
            max-height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a class="logo-link" href=""><img
                src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/5b/b4/8b/5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882.jpg"></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

You can create your code like this to resolve this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        nav {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: bisque;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        nav .align-left {
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: auto;
            height: 90%;
        }

        nav .align-right {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: 10px;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 11%;
            height: 20%;

        }

        nav .logo-link>img {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="align-left">
            <a class="logo-link" href=""><img
                    src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/5b/b4/8b/5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="align-right">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert tour image tag inside the  anchor tag  like this:
Text